# Does it matter when I step down the voltage in a two part conversion?

Tags: usb, voltage-regulator, serial, programming, ldo

I’m designing a 3.3V board using 328P that I want to program via usb, meaning I need a usb to serial conversion. My question is, does it matter if I regulate the voltage (MIC5129 LDO) between the USB and USB to serial converter, or after the usb to serial converter? I’m using CH340C to convert usb to serial.

Comment: The CH340C supports 3.3V operation, too. So you could power everything with 3.3V and would not even need a regulator?!